# Mathematical justification of Hartle-Hawking "no boundary" proposal

Tags: cosmology, quantum-gravity

[In Hartle-Hawking "no boundary" proposal](http://astrophysics.fic.uni.lodz.pl/100yrs/pdf/07/063.pdf) it is proposed that Riemannian spacetimes rather than Lorentzian dominated the path integral near the big bang.

Moments after the big bang however spacetimes with Lorentzian metrics started to dominate over the Riemannian. The dominance of the Riemannian spacetimes is characterized by positive definite metrics obtained by applying Wick rotation.

Now to compute the path integral some approximations are made and the process of analytic continuation is applied. What bothers me is analytic continuation of an approximate holomorphic function is not guaranteed to remain analytic in another region.

Why then this unreliable process applied—can one rely on this scheme which seems to be mathematically dubious?

Comment: I find your question tendentious and the wording misleading. The HH wave function is just a mathematical expression to determine a preferred state of the Universe on a three-sphere. It uses maths of a Euclidean spacetime because it is natural and the Ansätze are allowed to use any maths: you may still view the Euclideaniation as a math trick. Moreover, contrary to your implicit assertions, quantum field theory in a Euclidean spacetime is more mathematically well-behaved than quantum field theory (or QG) in the Lorentzian space, so the Euclideanization makes things better, not worse.

Comment: What I want to say is that HH were formulating a hypothesis about a state, and one can use *any* mathematical machinery to formulate a hypothesis. They used what they considered the most natural one, one which solved the WDW equation etc., and I tend to agree. Testing against evidence is what decides about the validity of a scientific hypothesis. I don't understand your problem. In the second part of the question, you assume that the expression in the Minkowski space are always "more true" than those in the Euclidean space. You have no evidence for that and in fact, I believe you're wrong.

Comment: Otherwise, approximating the HH state by a minisuperspace approximation etc. is always a problem and can lead to wrongness by itself. It's surely true. However, it may also be a good approximation for many problems. At any rate, this problem has nothing to do with the Euclideanization: the approximations done in the Euclidean signature are likely to be more accurate, much like in other cases where the Wick rotation is used. It is being used for a good reason - it makes the maths more convergent etc. E.g. path integrals only "rigorously" exist as a measure in the Euclidean signature.

Comment: *It uses maths of a Euclidean spacetime because it is natural and the Ansätze are allowed to use any maths:* Still doesn't explain what mechanism would cause the signature of the space-time manifold to change from Lorentzian to Riemannian. I think that is @sb1's original question - or at least that's my question.

Comment: @Sklivvz Reposting comments is not helping and is seemingly considered controversial, so I deleted your answer. Yet, @Luboš, please don't post long texts as comments, it is just hard to read.

Comment: @mbq: Although I understand the "controversy" angle, now this question doesn't have an answer, has not exactly appropriate comments, and, according to your best judgement, only @Lubos can copy and paste his (Creative-Commons licensed!) comments into an answer. Hopefully someone will provide a good answer, though. Especially I don't like the fact that comments can't be downvoted, edited or linked to.

Comment: @mbq: see also our [FAQ](http://physics.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion) - there is really no justification there for deletion.

Comment: @Sklivvz  I know it is legal, but it is obviously not desired by the community (votes, comments and flags); furthermore, your answer is just confusing and while it is downvoted, it suggests that Luboš's comments are somewhat wrong or even abusive.

Comment: @mbq - my answer did not suggest any of that, I believe you are reading things I haven't written.

Comment: @Sklivvz I wrote that the fact it is donwvoted suggests that.

Comment: @mbq: gotcha, makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

What is bothering you here is not Hartle-Hawking per-se, but the process of analytic continuation inside a path integral. This can be mystifying, because the actual functions which dominate the integral are never analytic, they are hardly ever continuous or even bounded. Usually they are distributional, so that they fluctuate in terrible ways at short distances. How can you analytically continue them?

But you don't ever continue the functions, you continue the path integral. The functions which you integrate over in imaginary time are of no relation to the functions which you integrate over for real times. The reason you can continue the path integral is because of positive energy--- the contribution of high-energy intermediate states decay quickly in positive imaginary time, and there are no negative energy contributions.